# Remove 'characters remaining' limit when editing questions and answers?

Tags: feature-request

I'm not sure if we have control over this setting, but what are your thoughts on removing the 'characters remaining' limit when editing questions and answers?

Sometimes when browsing the SE, I see code snippets that have trailing characters:

```
{% set lorem = ipsum %}'
```

It would be great to just be able to go in and remove that extra character, but I can't hit save until I have changed a minimum number of characters.

Comment: And here I thought I was the only one ever annoyed by this. But I'll admit I *love* minor edits, because I get annoyed by spelling, capitalization, or punctuation problems.

Comment: @MattStein Nope, you're not the only one!

Comment: Hey, I was able to remove that character as my only edit to your post. Not sure if that's because of my +2k reputation or because of this being the meta site?!

Comment: @carl It is because you have full editing priveleges, which you got after reaching 1k. 6 (min number) chars is required only for suggested edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, we don't have control over that. It's a standard Stack Exchange "feature", and applies equally to every SE site and SO.

There's some debate over the value of it, though it's unlikely to change anytime soon. I was reading a Meta thread about it the other day...

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits

Comment: I was worried that might be the case, thanks for the clarification Lindsey.